# sudo says unable to resolve host

Tags: sudo

I changed my hostname by `hostnamectl hostname Newname`, then when I run `sudo` the terminal will stop for one second then prints an error message.

```
sudo: unable to resolve host Newname: Temporary failure in name resolution
[sudo] password for Oldname:
```

The error message showing doesn't bother me much, but if I don't fix this, what security problem to my OS (easier to attack)?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: Almost certainly none, but mind the qualifier.

Longer explanation:

As `man sudoers` explains, there is room in a `sudoers` entry for a 'host' specification. This has mostly fallen into disuse these days, but it was a way to keep the same `sudoers` file identical across multiple servers without having to tweak it for every single host.

However, because that component still exists, `sudo` does a lookup for the current hostname to see if it may or may not match against any hypothetical entries in the `sudoers` file that might tell it whether or not to permit this sudo attempt.

Note that, like most security conscious software, `sudo` fails **safe** -- if it can't look up the host, *any* entry that specify a host value is considered invalid. So you're *very* likely safe -- as far as sudo is concerned, at least.

That *said*, being unable to look up its own name may not be a security issue by itself, but that is a thing it *should* be able to do, and it would be wise to try and find out *why* it can't, just in case the error is masking a bigger problem.

(My guess, based on experience, would be that when you changed the IP address and/or hostname of your current host, but you neglected to update `/etc/hosts` and/or didn't add a DNS entry for your new FQDN in whatever DNS server your network considers authoritative in this manner. So it gets a NXDOMAIN when trying to lookup `newname` and this error pops out.)